# How can I compensate lack of data in machine learning algorithm?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

Let's say I'm building an ANN for classifying data into A and B classes. Input data is **always** A or B. Let's say, I have sufficient amount of A samples but no samples of B. Can I build a network for clustering? Is there a way to do that?

Comment: unless you have some prior knowledge of how the B instances should look like, you cannot train a model that is able to correctly classify the B instances only on the A instances..

Comment: can you tell why did you choose to use neural networks, instead of employing some unsupervised methods? If the input data is A or B, and you do not have samples of B, does that mean you _expect_ them to appear during runtime? For this, I would simply estimate the probability distribution of the A samples and when a data point arrives, I would use its likelihood to determine whether it has high probability to be in the class A or not.

Comment: @JindraHelcl, then you don't even need any ML

Comment: You might want to look into anomaly detection. If you mostly have `A` samples but little or no `B` samples, then `A` can be considered the normal class and `B` can be considered an anomaly or an outlier. Anomaly detection deals with detecting this. What Jindra Helcl said is actually a basic anomaly detection method, and it is definitely part of ML: you're learning what something should look like so you'll know when you get something that doesn't look like it should.

Comment: @NikaGamkrelidze The simplicity of the method does not make it less ML.  The machine learning part here is to model the distribution of the A class. (Which you can do using for example the maximum likelihood estimate.)

Answer (score 0):

Such a scenario is termed as one-class classification. Take a look here to learn on how to use a framework such as Weka in Java to accomplish the same. https://weka.wikispaces.com/LibSVM